# Testing PreAuthorize annotations with custom beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-security

I'm trying to test my `PreAuthorize` annotations on my service methods in Spring Boot. I've managed to get it to evaluate the SPeL expressions, however it fails when referencing a custom bean.

Service method that I'm testing:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#eventId.id(), @eventTypePermission.target, @eventTypePermission.write())")
  public EventTypeId retrieveEventTypeIdForEventId(EventId eventId) {
    return null;
  }
```

Test code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
class TestConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler =
      new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new PermissionEvaluatorProxyTest());
    return expressionHandler;
  }

  @Bean
  public EventTypePermission permission() {
    return new EventTypePermission();
  }
}

@Component
@Slf4j
class PermissionEvaluatorProxyTest implements PermissionEvaluator {
  @Autowired
  public PermissionEvaluatorProxyTest() {
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasPermission(
    Authentication authentication, Object targetType, Object permission) {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasPermission(
    Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
    return true;
  }
}

@Import({TestConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={EventUpdater.class})
public class EventUpdaterTest {
  @Autowired
  private EventUpdater eventUpdater;
  @MockBean
  private EventRepository repository;
  @MockBean
  private EventTypePermission eventTypePermission;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
  }

  @Test
  @WithMockUser(username="test")
  public void test() {
    eventUpdater.retrieveEventTypeIdForEventId(new EventId(UUID.randomUUID()));
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'hasPermission(#eventId.id(), @eventTypePermission.target, @eventTypePermission.write())'
...
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E: No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'eventTypePermission'
```

Digging into it, it's failing because the bean resolver instance used by SPeL expression is null. Any thoughts on why this might be the case and how to set the bean resolver so that it's able to return an instance of `EventTypePermission`?

I also tried changing `@SpringBootTest(classes={EventUpdater.class})` to `@SpringBootTest(classes={EventUpdater.class, EventTypePermission.class})` with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working by explicitly setting the application context on the configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
class TestConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Autowired
  public TestConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }


  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler =
      new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new PermissionEvaluatorProxyTest());
    expressionHandler.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    return expressionHandler;
  }
}
```

Also had to update the `SpringTestClass` annotation to include `EventTypePermission`:
`@SpringBootTest(classes={EventUpdater.class, EventTypePermission.class})`, rather than define the Bean in the `TestConfig` class.